# Why the unmask() function is not properly working?

Tags: jquery

I create mask when the doc is ready

```
 $("input[type='tel']").mask("+7 (999) 999-9999", { placeholder: "+7 (___) ___-____" });
```

But when I try to get unmasked value , the function still gives to me the same masked value

```
   $("form").submit((e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("input[type='tel']").unmask(); // this funct 
        const nameEl = $("input[name*='name']").filter((index, item) => !!item.value)[0];
        const phoneEl = $("input[name*='phone']").filter((index, item) => !!item.value)[0];
        const name = nameEl && nameEl.value;
        const phone = phoneEl && phoneEl.value;
        console.log('phone 1', phone) // still give + 7 (333) 33-3333
        console.log('name 1', name)
    })
```

I was trying to unmask after I mask my value

```
$("input[type='tel']").mask("+7 (999) 999-9999", { placeholder: "+7 (___) ___-____" });
$("input[type='tel']").unmask();
```

And this workes , but it still doesn't work on submit event.
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Are you trying to submit from with jquery?

Comment: yes as written above ```$("form").submit```

Comment: One another question which format value you want to send on form submit "+7 (999) 999-9999" format or in "9999999999"  because unmask will remove mask and send simple plain value without "+7 (...."

Comment: I want to show for user masked +7 (999) 999-9999 so he couldn't  enter anything except numbers and for backend I want to send 999999999 format as backend receives such kind of format only

Comment: I have tried your code on my end its working as you want it which version of jquery and mask plugin you are using?

Comment: jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js